# Why do I get a flood of compiler errors when I include WinSock2.h?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock2

I'm trying to make a UDP Flood using WinSock2.h in c++ but I'm getting over 70 errors and 17 warnings on just WinSock2.h and all the errors are redefinitions, syntax errors from ws2def.h, and "different linkages". Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with WinSock2? If it is of any use I am using 64 bit Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <WinSock2.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <time.h>
  #include "wtypes.h"
  #include "Functions.h"
  #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") 
    //Get IP
    cin.getline(TargetIP, 17);

    //Get IP
    cout << "Enter the Port: ";
    cin >> nPort;
    cout << endl;

    //Initialize WinSock 2.2
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    //Create our UDP Socket
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    //Setup the target address
    targetAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    targetAddr.sin_port = htons(nPort);
    targetAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(TargetIP);

    //Get input from user
    cout << "Please specify the buffer size:";
    cin >> bufferSize;

    //Create our buffer
    char * buffer = new char[bufferSize];

    while(true){
        //send the buffer to target
        sendto(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL, (sockaddr *)&targetAddr, sizeof(targetAddr));
    }

    //Close Socket
    closesocket(s);

    //Cleanup WSA
    WSACleanup();

    //Cleanup our buffer (prevent memory leak)
    delete[]buffer;
```

Comment: There's more likely a problem with your code, but unless we see it we unfortunately can't help you.

Comment: At the very least, show us your code (minimal, complete example please).

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to post the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you may have a problem in the **order of inclusions**.

You are probably getting many errors along the lines of:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winsock2.h(2373): error C2375: 'WSAStartup': redefinition; different linkage
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winsock.h(867): note: see declaration of 'WSAStartup'
```

That's because `<windows.h>` includes `<winsock.h>` by default, and `<winsock.h>` provides many declarations that overlap with those in `<winsock2.h>`, which causes errors when `<winsock2.h>` is included *after* `<windows.h>`.

So, you may want to **include `<winsock2.h>` *before* `<windows.h>`**:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Or, as an alternative, you may try to define **`_WINSOCKAPI_`** to prevent the inclusion of `<winsock.h>` in `<windows.h>` with this preprocessor #undef-#define-#include *"dance"*:

```
#undef _WINSOCKAPI_
#define _WINSOCKAPI_  /* prevents <winsock.h> inclusion by <windows.h> */
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

I have to say that the definition of `_WINSOCKAPI_` macro to interfere in the ordinary header inclusion guard mechanics to prevent `<windows.h>` to include `<winsock.h>` sounds like an implementation-details-based fragile "hack", so I would probably prefer the first option.

But all in all this order of inclusion bug sounds to me like a bug in the Win32's headers, so the best thing would be for Microsoft to fix that.

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, a further alternative may be to **`#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`** *before* including `<windows.h>`. However, please note that this would prevent the inclusions of other Windows headers as well.

**P.S.**
If you are using *precompiled headers* (`"stdafx.h"` in the newly showed code in your question), you may want to pay attention to order of inclusions in there as well.

Comment: could you please explain why including that before windows makes a difference?

Comment: `<windows.h>` includes `<winsock.h>` by default, and `<winsock.h>` provides many declarations of `<winsock2.h>`, which causes errors when `<winsock2.h>` is included after `<windows.h>`.

Comment: Now I'm just seeing you pasted some source code in your question, and you are using precompiled headers (`#include "stdafx.h"`). Since `"stdafx.h"` is included _before_ the other headers, please make sure that you don't have this inclusion conflict in `stdafx.h` as well.

Comment: Okay that definitely helped, now I'm down to four errors all in my main.cpp "Initialization of buffer is skipped by case label" I think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of service. I know this was a subtle bug, and I was hit by that in my initial Win32 programming experiences :)

Comment: I believe you can just define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including Windows.h. That will avoid its dragging in WinSock, allowing you to include WinSock2.h as normal after including Windows.h.

Comment: @CodyGray: The problem is that WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN would avoid dragging in also other useful stuff, this is why I'm not a big fan of this option. Anyway, those are all hacks around a bug out of our control.

Comment: In my experience, most of what it excludes is very rarely used, and can be explicitly included thereafter if really needed. About the only thing that cannot are the resource IDs (OBM_* and etc.)

Comment: @CodyGray: There are several headers in the WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN preprocessor #ifndef branch in <Windows.h>. I'm not sure if other code may depend on those. All in all, I think the best thing to do would be to fix this bizarre order of inclusion constraint in Windows headers.

Comment: Well, you nailed the problem already. The two libraries are not meant to coexist. WinSock2 *replaces* the original WinSock. If I remember correctly, the Windows master headers actually include WinSock2 if you're targeting a new enough version of Windows, making this not an actual problem. But I could be wrong, it's been quite a while since I looked at this.